# Why is there a back slash in tailwind css class names?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to learn and use a new utility framework which is getting very popular these days. [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/)

When I compiled my css using the instructions in the docs, I saw a lot of css class names have colon `:` in them and it is preceded by a back slash `\`

Why is that? Is that to make CSS understand that there is a `:` there and not to escape it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Tailwind uses class names with colons as part of its support for Responsive Design. In particular, a class name such as

```
tablet:bold
```

Means that the properties defined in the class `bold` should be applied but only if the media matches the media query defined as `tablet`.

A colon is a perfectly valid character in an HTML5 class name. It is, however, a reserved character in a CSS selector. So, if you want to select elements with a class whose name contains a colon, you need to escape the colon.

So, if you have HTML like this:

```
<p class="one:two"></p>
```

And you want to select that element, the corresponding query selector would be something like:

```
.one\:two
```

Comment: Very useful and simple answer

Comment: It actually takes two backslashes in javascript: `document.querySelector(".one\\:two");  `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: @GregGum, important to note. Jaascript also uses the slash escape character for interpolating non-printable characters into a string, such as a `tab` character. So when you use a string to specify the selecor you need to escape the escape character for ti to actually work. Passing around escape sequences with wild abandon can be difficult to debug.