# Why backslash after a .class in css?

Tags: css

I have seen the following CSS in an example -

```
.hover\:bg-gray-800:hover {
    background-color: #2d3748;
 }
```

My question is what is the usage of backslash here?

Comment: are you using tailwind?

Comment: Old code or new code? If old, probably a hack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558601/strange-backslash-and-behavior-in-css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a back slash in tailwind css class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52515760/why-is-there-a-back-slash-in-tailwind-css-class-names)

Comment: hint: theres no pseudo selector `:bg-gray-800`

Comment: @DanielA.White I am not sure about tailwind or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon in CSS has a special meaning; pseudo class selectors start with this special char, like `:hover` (which your code example actually has at the end), `:active`, `:first-child`.

The `\` tells CSS to treat the following character not as a character with a special CSS meaning. This is generally called *escaping*.

It allows for usage of CSS class names **containing a :** in HTML:

```css
.foo\:hover { color: orange; padding: 3em; }

.foo\:hover:hover { background-color: orange; color: white; }
```

```html
<div class="foo:hover">foo bar here, hover me</div>
```

Comment: That's great. Not the thing is clear to me. Thanks.